# Can you divide this by $7$ without a remainder ? $ 13^{101}-13^{95} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Just need some help with basic math. How do i know if i can divide this expression by $7$ without a remainder ?

$ 13^{101}-13^{95} $

Comment: Check whether $(13^6-1)$ is divisble by $7$, since you know $13^{95}$ isn't.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** A number $n$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $n\equiv 0\pmod{7}$. Note that $13 \equiv 2\cdot 7 - 1\equiv -1\pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 3):

Fermat's little theorem is sufficient : Note $13^{101}-13^{95}=13^{95}\cdot (13^6-1)$

Since $7$ is a prime not dividing $13$, we have $7|13^6-1$ because of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: If you factor it in the form $a^{94}(a^7-a)$, then you don't even need to check that $7\not\mid a$.

Comment: An easier way is using Stahl's idea $13^{101}-13^{95}\equiv (-1)^{101}-(-1)^{95}=-1-(-1)=0\mod 7$

Comment: @BarryCipra I just realized that if $7|13$ would hold, we could also conclude $7|13^{95}\cdot (13^6-1)$ easily. But we do need that $7$ is prime. The advantage of Stahl's approach (apart from being much easier here) is that we do not need that $7$ is prime because $13$ happens to be congruent to $-1$ modulo $7$.

Comment: So would that mean it is divisible right?

Comment: Yes, it is divisible by $7$ becuase $13^6-1$ is.

Comment: My factorization would also allow to conclude that $7$ is a divisor , if it dividides the base , easily because in this case, the first factor would be divisible by $7$. Stahl's solution is very nice in this case, but if the remainder modulo $7$ is not $\pm 1$, we will have to reduce the exponent as well to get a result (without electronic help).

Comment: @Peter, I agree, either $a^{95}(a^6-1)$ or $a^{94}(a^7-a)$ works.  I also agree that Stahl's very nice solution avoids Fermat, but at the expense of a (simple) computation.  Our way(s) avoid that (less simple) computation if, say, you ask if $7$ divides $864197522^{101}-864197522^{95}$.

Comment: Side remark:  I deleted and rethought the remark you replied to in your last comment.